# Porque me dice que "No hay niguna fila en la posicion 0" si en BD si existen datos

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, visual-studio, webforms

tengo el error en el string idempresa, ya que al momento de que se manda llamar de bd dice que no hay ninguna fila en la posición 0 pero en bd si me trae datos al momento d ejecutar el query.

"

```
DataTable dt = Cls_General.ObtenerDatosUsuario(Convert.ToString(Session["idUsuario"]));
 string idempresa = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["idEmpresa"]); //Esta linea da el error
 string region = Convert.ToString(dt.Rows[0]["region"]);
 int idUsu = Convert.ToInt32(Session["idUsuario"]);
```

"

Aqui esta el Query
"

```
SELECT NoEmpleado, tipo_Acceso, Region_SAP region, idEmpresa_SAP idEmpresa, Empresa_SAP, idSucursal_SAP 
        idSucursal, Sucursal_SAP
 FROM [SintesisCumplimiento].[dbo].[Usuarios]
 WHERE idUsuario = @idusuario
 AND Estatus = 1
```

"

y no encuentro en donde podría estar el error, podrían apoyarme muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: el DataTable sí está recibiendo y almacenando datos?

Comment: primero tenes que saber si tu metodo Cls_General.ObtenerDatosUsuarios, te trae la informacion y corrobrar que tu Session["IdUsuario"] tenga la info correcta que ese metodo pide.